# How to make pandas read csv input as string, not as an url

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm trying to load a csv (from an API response) into pandas, but keep getting an error

```
"ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows" and "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'"fwefwe","fwef..."
```

indicating that pandas interprets it as an url, not a string.

The code below causes the errors above.

```
fake_csv='"fwefwe","fwefw","fwefew";"2","5","7"'
df = pd.read_csv(fake_csv, encoding='utf8')
df
```

How do I force pandas to interpret my argument as a csv string?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `StringIO`:

```
import io
fake_csv='"fwefwe","fwefw","fwefew";"2","5","7"'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(fake_csv), encoding='utf8', sep=',', lineterminator=';')
df
```

Result:

```
Out[30]: 
   fwefwe  fwefw  fwefew
0       2      5       7
```